# bootstrap dropdown on hover but main dropdown is still a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to make the bootstrap dropdown on hover and still make the main button a link like if i click the dropdown button instead of a dropdown it should go to a different page

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="body-wrap">
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="www.google.com" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="www.google.com" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my JS

```
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
});
```

Here is a code pen sample
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/boNGBY

Comment: what do you mean by main button? change # to say page2.html or wherever you want the link to direct to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the (data-toggle="dropdown") from your anchor tag().
Dropdown